# PHP script - detect whether running under linux or Windows?

Tags: php, windows, linux, operating-system, detect

I have a PHP script that may be placed on a windows system or a linux system. I need to run different commands in either case.

How can I detect which environment I am in? (preferably something PHP rather than clever system hacks)

### Update

To clarify, the script is running from the command line.

Comment: After performing benchmarks, it seems that any differences in performance between `\strncasecmp(\PHP_OS, 'WIN', 3) === 0`, `\strtoupper(\substr(\PHP_OS, 0, 3)) === 'WIN'` and `\stripos(\PHP_OS, 'WIN')` are below 15%. Since all three solutions only take roughly 100 nanoseconds, this would be a micro-optimization, anyway. So choose whatever solution you like. Finally, you may argue that `\strncasecmp(\PHP_OS, 'WIN', 3) === 0` is the most readable.

Answer (score 274, accepted):

Check the value of the [`PHP_OS` constant<sup>*Docs*</sup>](http://php.net/manual/reserved.constants.php#constant.php-os).

It will give you various values on Windows like `WIN32`, `WINNT` or `Windows`.

See as well: [*Possible Values For: PHP_OS*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/738823/367456) and [`php_uname`<sup>*Docs*</sup>](http://php.net/php_uname):

```
if (strtoupper(substr(PHP_OS, 0, 3)) === 'WIN') {
    echo 'This is a server using Windows!';
} else {
    echo 'This is a server not using Windows!';
}
```

Comment: What value would it be if it's Windows? There is nothing in the docs that I can see.

Comment: Shabbyrobe: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/738823/possible-values-for-php-os

Comment: `stripos(PHP_OS, 'WIN') === 0` can be used instead, arguably more readable / simple.

Comment: @dw1 - it would still work as it searches for "win" at the beginning.

Comment: And with php8 we now have `if (str_starts_with(strtoupper(PHP_OS), 'WIN')) {`

Comment: There is also a posix_uname() but it will not exist on some Windows environments. it will work in mingw/cygwin, but not in a dos/windows compiled php. Perhaps do a `if(function_exists('posix_uname'))` test before making a call to it.

Comment: @Shabbyrobe the value varies depending on the php installed. A windows/dos based php install will report something like 'WINNT'. Cygwin will return 'CYGWIN'. Not sure what mingw returns.

Comment: I've noticed also that some commands such as the 'uname' functions will return mixed case e.g. 'Windows'. So another way to check other than stripos would be `preg_match('/win/i', PHP_OS)` or `preg_match('/win/i', php_uname())`. If you want to be more specific, you can put search ^win as it's usually the first word in the result.  But the non ^ version will also match 'CYGWIN'

Answer (score 82):

You can check if the directory separator is `/` (for unix/linux/mac) or `\` on windows. The constant name is `DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR`.

```
if (DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR === '/') {
    // unix, linux, mac
}

if (DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR === '\\') {
    // windows
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately this does not work with Windows 7 and Zend Server. In this case DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR is also '\'

Comment: @Achim What do you mean? Zend Server is server software, not an OS. Windows 7 *should* return \.

Comment: `strpos(__FILE__,92)` exploits the same behaviour; `PATH_SEPARATOR>":"` returns true for Windows too (PATH_SEPARATOR is ":" on all other OSs).

Comment: Turned this into a function: `function is_linux(){return (DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR == '/') ? true : false;}`

Answer (score 41):

```
if (strncasecmp(PHP_OS, 'WIN', 3) == 0) {
    echo 'This is a server using Windows!';
} else {
    echo 'This is a server not using Windows!';
}
```

seems like a bit more elegant than the accepted answer. The aforementioned detection with DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR is the fastest, though.

Comment: Sorry, but this doesn't work right if you're using a Mac server, since in Mac you get a string that contains "DARWIN", which also contains "WIN", so in a Mac server you'll get "This is a server using Windows!" which is not true.

Comment: Well, this is not quite true. Notice that `strncasecmp` takes **the first** _n_ characters, not just any _n_ characters. If you tried it, you would have found out that `strncasecmp('DARWIN', 'WIN', 3) == 0` evaluates to `false`.

Answer (score 32):

Starting with PHP 7.2.0 you can detect the running O.S. using the constant `PHP_OS_FAMILY`:

```
if (PHP_OS_FAMILY === "Windows") {
  echo "Running on Windows";
} elseif (PHP_OS_FAMILY === "Linux") {
  echo "Running on Linux";
}
```

See the [official PHP documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/reserved.constants.php#constant.php-os-family) for its possible values.

Comment: @Stef According to 3v4l, it's only available in PHP 7.2 https://3v4l.org/CBpG4

Comment: Being that almost everybody should really being using PHP version 7.2+, this is most elegant answer

Answer (score 18):

Note that [PHP_OS reports the OS that PHP was *built* on](http://php.net/manual/en/function.php-uname.php), which is not necessarily the same OS that it is currently running on.

If you are on PHP >= 5.3 and just need to know whether you're running on Windows or not-Windows then testing whether one of the [Windows-specific constants](http://php.net/manual/en/info.constants.php) is defined may be a good bet, e.g.:

```
$windows = defined('PHP_WINDOWS_VERSION_MAJOR');
```

Comment: 1. Correct is not where PHP was built ON but for what it was built FOR
2. This applies to the defined windows related constant the same way...

Comment: Anyway PHP built for Windows can not be run on unix, can it?

Answer (score 10):

According to [Predefined Constants: User Contributed Notes](https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.constants.php#113172) Volker's and rdcapasso solution, you can simply create helper class like this:

```
<?php

class System {

    const OS_UNKNOWN = 1;
    const OS_WIN = 2;
    const OS_LINUX = 3;
    const OS_OSX = 4;

    /**
     * @return int
     */
    static public function getOS() {
        switch (true) {
            case stristr(PHP_OS, 'DAR'): return self::OS_OSX;
            case stristr(PHP_OS, 'WIN'): return self::OS_WIN;
            case stristr(PHP_OS, 'LINUX'): return self::OS_LINUX;
            default : return self::OS_UNKNOWN;
        }
    }

}
```

**Usage:**

```
if(System::getOS() == System::OS_WIN) {
  // do something only on Windows platform
}
```

Answer (score 9):

The [php_uname](http://php.net/manual/en/function.php-uname.php) function can be used to detect this.

```
echo php_uname();
```

Answer (score 8):

This should work in PHP 4.3+:

```
if (strtolower(PHP_SHLIB_SUFFIX) === 'dll')
{
    // Windows
}
else
{
    // Linux/UNIX/OS X
}
```

Answer (score 5):

To detect whether it's Windows, OS X or Linux:

```
if (stripos(PHP_OS, 'win') === 0) {
    // code for windows
} elseif (stripos(PHP_OS, 'darwin') === 0) {
    // code for OS X
} elseif (stripos(PHP_OS, 'linux') === 0) {
    // code for Linux
}
```

`stripos` is a bit slower than `substr` in this particular case, yet it's efficient enough for such a small task, and more elegant.

Comment: Although the code is simple enough, this answer does not stand on its own: A great answer doesn't force one to read the question when coming from a search engine, because it is self-contained.

Answer (score 5):

You can check if a constant exists in PHP >5.3.0 ([manual](http://php.net/manual/en/info.constants.php))

```
if (defined('PHP_WINDOWS_VERSION_BUILD')) {
    // is Windows
}
```

Previously, this method was used in Symfony. Now they use a [different method](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/commit/559273ec1c8d8b00156a36b13230a82f3d3b554c):

```
if ('\\' === DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR) {
    // is Windows
}
```

Answer (score 4):

**Core Predefined Constants:** https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.constants.php which has the `PHP_OS (string)` constant.

Or if you want to detect the OS of the client:

```
<?php
    echo $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'] . "\n\n";

    $browser = get_browser(null, true);
    print_r($browser);
?>
```

From https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.get-browser.php

---

According to your edit you can refer to this dublicate [PHP Server Name from Command Line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/626416/php-server-name-from-command-line)

You can use

```
string php_uname ([ string $mode = "a" ] )
```

So

```
php_uname("s")
```

> 's': Operating system name. eg.
> FreeBSD.

Would do the trick for you, see here http://php.net/manual/en/function.php-uname.php

Answer (score 1):

If you want to check if running under Linux, just test if `(PHP_OS === 'Linux')`. No need to use strtolower() and substr().

Answer (score -2):

```
function isWin(){
 if (strtolower(substr(PHP_OS, 0, 3)) === 'win' || PHP_SHLIB_SUFFIX == 'dll' || PATH_SEPARATOR == ';') {
    return true;
 } else {
    return false;
 }
}
```