# PHP - Server name from the command line

Tags: php

Apparently `$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']` is set only when executing the php script from the browser.

Is there any way to know the server's name from the command line ?

I tried `php_uname("n")` as proposed in this discussion [PHP Server Name from Command Line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/626416/php-server-name-from-command-line). But it doesn't work for me, it returns my username instead of the server's name.

Comment: take `_DIR__` and work from there?

Comment: exec("hostname") if you are on *nix machine.

Comment: well, you need to know that there are some different between SAPI's in PHP, when you are running a PHP script in your web browser, you are using the **HTTP Server** SAPI ( Apache2 or nginx or whatever ) , while when you are using your PHP from the command line, you are using the CLI SAPI, that's why the

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no "server" involved when executing a script from the command line. You're just running a program on a *machine*. That machine isn't per se associated with any domain name. One machine can run multiple web servers which are each responsible for several domains. So `$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']`, which comes from the web server's configuration (e.g. Apache's `ServerName` directive), only makes sense in the context of an incoming HTTP request.

You'll need to manually configure/tell your script what domain it should work on, it can't detect it without context.

Answer (score 0):

well, you need to know that there are some different between SAPI's in PHP, when you are running a PHP script in your web browser, you are using the **HTTP Server** SAPI ( Apache2 or nginx or whatever ), so the returned data in the $_SERVER variable will depends on the headers that the web server itself will throw to PHP, While in the terminal you are running PHP Under CLI SAPI which is serverless so to speak *Unless you are using the [built-in php server](http://php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.webserver.php)*.

Take a look at the $_SERVER manual page :-

> `$_SERVER` is an array containing information such as headers, paths,
>   and script locations. The entries in this array are created by the web
>   server. There is no guarantee that every web server will provide any
>   of these; servers may omit some, or provide others not listed here.
>   That said, a large number of these variables are accounted for in the
>   » CGI/1.1 specification, so you should be able to expect those.

which is mean - again - that the data that will $_SERVER variable will hold will depends on the information that the *web server* will return/throw .

---

As a workaround you can check if the script is running under the CLI SAPI, and then set some [custom values for the `$_SERVER`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29987973/2359679) variable

Answer (score -1):

Use print_r($_SERVER) to see all the attributes on server variables. Maybe another one will fit your needs.

Cheers!

Comment: This wil result in an small output. Most SERVER variables have no value when excecuted via the commandline :) One of those without value is SERVER_NAME :)